# Generate entity from an existing table

Tags: php, symfony4

I have a already created table:

```
CREATE TABLE `jt_version` (
    `version` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '103',
    `model` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '108'
```

From this table, I have generated an entity.

```
 php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
```

This entity generated creates something like this:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"comment"="103"})
 */
private $version;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="model", type="string", length=4, nullable=false, options={"default"="''","comment"="108"})
 */
private $model= '\'\'';
```

My question is from where the value of model is getting set. In above case the `$model` value is `'\'\''`

Is that correct or I need to make some change?

Comment: It is default value that you have specified in CREATE TABLE query `DEFAULT '' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is set from the default value which you have specified in this

```php
@ORM\Column(name="model", type="string", length=4, nullable=false, options={"default"="''","comment"="108"}}
```